# Rest API 403 Access Denied

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, rest-api

I testing the REST API with the Fire Fox Rest API Client. But I am getting 403 Access Denined. I have checked with all the permissions as mentioned in the other answers but could not get through. I am new to REST API.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

However, by looking at below API, I have not found any information regarding Login.

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resource_customers.html

**UPDATE 2:**

I am able to get the Login screen as below.

[image]

**Now the question** is from where will I get oauth_token ?

Comment: this might be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045800/how-to-use-postman-rest-client-with-magento-rest-api-with-oauth-how-to-get-toke

Comment: @Magento learner : Can you please explain what you did on admin section for api settings please add screen shot with steps

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, I have implemented exactly the same configuration as in http://inchoo.net/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal, can you check an update?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that your `user->role` has permission for customer if you are fetching customer

Please go to `system->permission->role` and add permission for your user role for access.

Comment: Thanks, I have given all the access. Also check my update

Comment: my rest api : 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/customers return 403 access denied error, but products return wokring -> 127.0.0.1/anusthana/api/rest/products  -> working. May i know what is the error? @Murtuza Zabuawala

Answer (score 0):

The URL passed for authorization has to be over https, otherwise you get the error message.

```
https://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize
```

Comment: where should I place this url?

Comment: in your rest api  url bar

Comment: Which Data should I pass in the Field Section?

Comment: https://172.16.60.51/magento1922/api/rest/customers

Comment: use this url : [https://172.16.60.51/magento1922/api/rest/customers]

Comment: In the client and then get the token?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot provided, I can see you have not provided the OAuth 1.0 credentials (consumer key & secret, token key & secret) as RESTClient would have shown a red dropdown labelled `OAuth 1.0` on the right of `Request` as in the screenshot below
[image: oauth parameters provided]

To enter the OAuth 1.0 credentials, select `Authentication` from the top menu, then `OAuth 1.0`. You can then fill in the text boxes with their corresponding credentials and save it by checking `Remember this signature`

[image]

In the `Settings` tab, change the `Signature method` to `HMAC-SHA1`

Then you are good to go.

In case you do not have any OAuth credentials, follow [this post by Joshua Austill](https://jlaustill.github.io/2016/10/how-to-get-a-token-from-magento-1_x-rest-api)